# Produce weekly average plots from large dataset in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am quite new to R and have been struggling with trying to convert my data and could use some much needed help.
I have a dataframe which is approx. 70,000*2. This data covers a whole year (52 weeks/365 days). A portion of it looks like this:

```
Create.Date.Time    Ticket.ID
1   2013-06-01 12:59:00 INCIDENT684790
2   2013-06-02 07:56:00 SERVICE684793
3   2013-06-02 09:39:00 SERVICE684794
4   2013-06-02 14:14:00 SERVICE684796
5   2013-06-02 17:20:00 SERVICE684797
6   2013-06-03 07:20:00 SERVICE684799
7   2013-06-03 08:02:00 SERVICE684839
8   2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684841
9   2013-06-03 08:04:00 SERVICE684842
10  2013-06-03 08:08:00 SERVICE684843
```

I am trying to get the number of tickets in every hour of the week (that is, hour 1 to hour 168) for each week. Hour 1 would start on Monday at 00.00, and hour 168 would be Sunday 23.00-23.59. This would be repeated for each week. I want to use the Create.Date.Time data to calculate the hour of the week the ticket is in, say for:

```
2013-06-01 12:59:00 INCIDENT684790 - hour 133, 
2013-06-03 08:08:00 SERVICE684843 - hour 9
```

I am then going to do averages for each hour and plot those. I am completely at a loss as to where to start. Could someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing the plotting aspect of your question, is this the format of data you are trying to get? This uses the package `lubridate` which you might have to install (`install.packages("lubridate",dependencies=TRUE)`).

```
library(lubridate)
##
Events <- paste(
  sample(c("INCIDENT","SERVICE"),20000,replace=TRUE),
  sample(600000:900000,20000)
)
t0 <- as.POSIXct(
  "2013-01-01 00:00:00",
  format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
  tz="America/New_York")
Dates <- sort(t0 + sample(0:(3600*24*365-1),20000))
Weeks <- week(Dates)
wDay <- wday(Dates,label=TRUE)
Hour <- hour(Dates)
##
hourShift <- function(time,wday){
  hShift <- sapply(wday, function(X){
    if(X=="Mon"){
      0
    } else if(X=="Tues"){
      24*1
    } else if(X=="Wed"){
      24*2
    } else if(X=="Thurs"){
      24*3
    } else if(X=="Fri"){
      24*4
    } else if(X=="Sat"){
      24*5
    } else {
      24*6
    }
  })
  ##
  tOut <- hour(time) + hShift + 1
  return(tOut)
}
##
weekHour <- hourShift(time=Dates,wday=wDay)
##
Data <- data.frame(
  Event=Events,
  Timestamp=Dates,
  Week=Weeks,
  wDay=wDay,
  dayHour=Hour,
  weekHour=weekHour,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
```

This gives you:

```
> head(Data)
            Event           Timestamp Week wDay dayHour weekHour
1  SERVICE 783405 2013-01-01 00:13:55    1 Tues       0       25
2 INCIDENT 860015 2013-01-01 01:06:41    1 Tues       1       26
3 INCIDENT 808309 2013-01-01 01:10:05    1 Tues       1       26
4 INCIDENT 835509 2013-01-01 01:21:44    1 Tues       1       26
5  SERVICE 769239 2013-01-01 02:04:59    1 Tues       2       27
6  SERVICE 762269 2013-01-01 02:07:41    1 Tues       2       27
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking to get Will try your code and adapt it to my data to see if it works! Thanks

Comment: @user3770767 You're welcome - be aware that the `week()` function in `lubridate` defines 53 weeks in a year (as is convention for many other programs, like `SQL`s `DATEPART(WEEK, *somedate*)`) since there are more than 52*7=364 days in a year. I'm not sure how you want to handle that, but one option would be to merge week 53 with week 52 (`Data[Data$Week==53,"Week"] <- 52`); or you could just drop these observations (`Data <- subset(Data,Week < 53)`) since it's only 2/7 of a whole week (3/7 if it's a leap year).

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. I will be leaving the 53th week as well since it will not make any difference to my plots.